# Recording user input to affect if statement java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, user-input

I was wondering how I would go about this. I want to make it that every time the user inputs "paper" it adds a count and when the count is 3 and over, the computer chooses scissors for the next one. I have my code here and I was wondering if I'm heading in the right direction.

```
 double PC = Math.random();

 String User = UI.askString("Enter choice: ");
 int paper = 0;
 paper ++;
 int finalCount = 0;

 UI.clearGraphics();

 if(PC < 0.3333 || paper > 3){ 
    UI.drawImage("scissors-left.jpg", 100, 100);
    UI.drawString("PC chose scissors", 100, 90);

    if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
         UI.drawImage("rock-right.jpg", 300, 100);
         UI.drawString("you win", 300, 90);
         finalCount = finalCount + 1;


        }

    if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
         UI.drawImage("scissors-right.jpg", 300, 100);
         UI.drawString("tie", 300, 90);
         finalCount = finalCount + 0;


        }   

    if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
         UI.drawImage("paper-right.jpg", 300, 100);
         UI.drawString("you lose", 300, 90);
         finalCount = finalCount - 1;
         paper ++;

    }

}

else if(PC > 0.667){ 
     UI.drawImage("rock-left.jpg", 100, 100);
     UI.drawString("PC chose rock", 100, 90);
    if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
         UI.drawImage("rock-right.jpg", 300, 100);
         UI.drawString("tie", 300, 90);
         finalCount = finalCount + 0;


        }

    if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
         UI.drawImage("scissors-right.jpg", 300, 100);
         UI.drawString("you lose", 300, 90);
         finalCount = finalCount - 1;


        }   

    if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
         UI.drawImage("paper-right.jpg", 300, 100);
         UI.drawString("you win", 300, 90);
         finalCount = finalCount + 1;
         paper++;

    }

}
else{ 
     UI.drawImage("paper-left.jpg", 100, 100);
     UI.drawString("PC chose paper", 100, 90);
    if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
         UI.drawImage("rock-right.jpg", 300, 100);
         UI.drawString("you lose", 300, 90);
         finalCount = finalCount - 1;


        }

    if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
         UI.drawImage("scissors-right.jpg", 300, 100);
         UI.drawString("you win", 300, 90);
         finalCount = finalCount + 1;



        }   

    if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
         UI.drawImage("paper-right.jpg", 300, 100);
         UI.drawString("tie", 300, 90);
         finalCount = finalCount + 0;
         paper ++;

    }

}

return finalCount;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: can you explain with variable PC does in your code?

Comment: whats the use of final count and why in case of sciccors you doing finalCount+0, does it make any difference ? also why you incrmenting paper just after initializing it to 0 ?

Comment: PC selects a random number between 0 & 1 using Math.random(); and depending on what number it selects, it does rock, paper or scissors, depending on the if statments. So if the PC chooses a number below 0.333, the PC displays scissors and depending on what the user input is while the PC does scissors, it displays you won if user chose rock and puts a count towards the final count which is +1 for winning, + 0 for tie and - 1 for losing. This does not relate to my query as this is linked to a method that calls upon this method that needs it to return finalCount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of repeated code in your program.  When you have this much repetition, you should look for ways to avoid the repetition.

For example, you test whether `User` equals `"rock"`, and if it's true you draw `"rock-right.jpg"`.  But this test, and the code to draw the image, are the same no matter what `PC` is.  So you can move this out of the `if`'s that test `PC`, and do this once, before you say `if (PC < 0.3333 || paper > 3)`:

```
if(User.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
     UI.drawImage("rock-right.jpg", 300, 100);
}
else if (User.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) {
     UI.drawImage("scissors-right.jpg", 300, 100);
}
else if (User.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) {
     UI.drawImage("paper-right.jpg", 300, 100);
}
```

Then you might be able to figure out that you don't even need the `if` statements, since you're repeating the `drawImage` each time with almost the same parameters:

```
UI.drawImage(User.toLowerCase() + "-right.jpg", 300, 100);
```

So 9 `drawImage` calls have been reduced to 1.

Another thing you can do is not to use so many `if`s to check each combination of rock, paper, scissors.  Suppose that we translated each string to a number, with rock=0, paper=1, scissors=2.  Here's a table showing who the winner would be for each combination:

```
PC     \ User |  rock=0  |  paper=1  | scissors=2
rock=0        |   Tie    |   User    |   PC
paper=1       |   PC     |   Tie     |   User
scissors=2    |   User   |   PC      |   Tie
```

Note that the rows follow a pattern: when you go to the next row, the "winner" values are rotated one place to the right (with the one on the right moving over to the left), and this pattern continues all the way down (OK, only one more row).  But any time you see this kind of pattern, you should think about using the `%` (modulo) operator to find the answer.  In this case, it will work like this:

```
if (PC == User)
    it's a tie
else if ((PC + 1) % 3 == User)
    the user wins
else
    the PC wins
```

This works for all 9 combinations, which should simplify your code a lot instead of having 9 combinations of nested `if` statements.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but how do I convert the string to int and then use it in the code like you suggested. Sorry, I am a beginner and this is my first year doing coding. @ajb

Comment: The simplest way is to use `if` statements, or a `switch` statement, like `if (User.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) { userValue = 0; } else if (User.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) { userValue = 1; } ... then use `userValue` in your computations.  A `Map` is also a good way, but since you're a beginner I won't throw too much at you all at once.  The PC's value can be generated from your random number: `PCValue = (int) (PC * 3);`.  Multiplying by 3 results in a random number from 0 to 2.9999999..., and `(int)` throws away everything after the decimal point.